# Can not assign to method group

Tags: c#, methods, ado.net

```
public bool AddArchitecture(DataSet Architecture)
    {
        base.SQL = "sp_InsertArchitecture";
        base.InitializeCommand();
        base.AddParameter("@Architecture_ID",
            SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 16,
            Architecture.Tables.Add("Architecture").Rows.Add("Architecture_ID"));
        base.AddParameter("@Architecture_Name",
            SqlDbType.VarChar, 25,
            Architecture.Tables.Add("Architecture").Rows.Add("Architecture_Name"));
        base.AddParameter("@Architecture_Description",
            SqlDbType.VarChar, 25,
            Architecture.Tables.Add("Architecture").Rows.Add("Architecture_Description"));
        base.AddParameter("@Architecture_Date_Added",
            SqlDbType.DateTime, 8,
            Architecture.Tables.Add("Architecture").Rows.Add("Architecture_Date_Added"));

        **AddArchitecture** = ExecuteStoredProcedure; This is where I get the error.
    }
```

Comment: More info: what are you trying to do, and what do you mean by assigining to the method name? It's almost like VB6 style properties...but it's not...

Comment: What's `ExecuteStoredProcedure`? Are you trying to return a value from this method or what?

Comment: ExecuteStoredProcedure runs ExecuteNonQuery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a VB programmer, first time working in C#, right?

I *think* you want

```
return ExecuteStoredProcedure();
```

instead.

Comment: Took the words out of my mouth :)

Comment: It's that obvious. Yes I want to get away from VB and learn C#.